# Snowflake copy grants and data share

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a question regarding COPY GRANTS option while cloning object and data share,
what happens when we clone table and use copy grants option and the source table is  shared through data share, does new table automatically gets shared?

Answer (score 0):

No - grants and shares are different things.

I am not aware of any process in Snowflake that, as one of its activities, automatically adds an object to a share. This is very deliberate, from a data security perspective. If you want to share data then you need to take an explicit action to add that data to a share.